# What is the correct preposition here in this expression?

Tags: prepositions

Let's say I am talking about an accident that occurred during an F1 race

> Rather than overtaking **through/in/from** left, the driver(B) did the opposite and caused an accident as the driver ahead(A) did not expect B to come **through/in** right.

So what is the right preposition to use in this expression?

Comment: *Overtake* or *pass* **on** the left or right.

Comment: I think *from* is also acceptable racing terminology, but as StoneyB points out, it is *the* left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of prepositions is highly idiomatic in many cases, and this is one of them.  Generally, one passes "on" the left or right, as Stoney says.  However, as Jim says, "overtaking" can use either from or on.  "Come from the right" is correct, however, although "come by on the right" or "come through on the right" could also be used.